# About load supported cultures from DB in .NET CORE

Tags: database, .net-core, localization, cultureinfo

I have a Language entity with all supported languages in my db, each language has a culture string attribute. I want to load supported cultures from DB.

In my service initializer I have it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... previous configuration not shown

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        opts =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                new CultureInfo("fr"),
            };

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
}
```

How I can access my DB context inside it?
There is any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an out of the box solution for this.

However, you can implement your own middleware that achieves this by using ASP.Net's `RequestLocalizationMiddleware`:

```cs
public class CustomRequestLocalizationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;

    public CustomRequestLocalizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* You can inject services here, such as DbContext or IDbConnection*/)
    {
        // You can search your database for your supported and/or default languages here
        // This query will execute for all requests, so consider using caching
        var cultures = await Task.FromResult(new[] { "en" });
        var defaultCulture = await Task.FromResult("en");

        // You can configure the options here as you would do by calling services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>()
        var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
            .AddSupportedCultures(cultures)
            .AddSupportedUICultures(cultures)
            .SetDefaultCulture(defaultCulture);

        // Finally, we instantiate ASP.Net's default RequestLocalizationMiddleware and call it
        var defaultImplementation = new RequestLocalizationMiddleware(next, Options.Create(options), loggerFactory);
        await defaultImplementation.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Then, we inject the required services and use the custom middleware in `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` as follows:

```cs
services.AddLocalization()
/* ... */
app.UseMiddleware<CustomRequestLocalizationMiddleware>()
```

Do not call `app.UseRequestLocalization()`, because this would call ASP.Net's `RequestLocalizationMiddleware` again with the default options, and override the culture that has been resolved previously.